# Can Cantor's theorem prove that $\mathbb N$ is uncountable (paradox)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am struggling a bit trying to understand Cantor's theorem about the reals being uncountable.

How can you choose a real number that is different from all real numbers in an enumeration $S$?

I completely get the trick about finding a real $r \notin S$ by changing one digit from each element of $S$, but how can you do that when $S$ in infinite? I mean, you would never actually produce a number $r$, because you would just be in a race where you try to exhaust $S$, but you never reach the end of the list as $S$ is infinite.

Also, wouldn't a similar diagonalization strategy prove that the natural numbers are uncountable? That would contradict the fact that a set $A$ is countable if $|A| = |\mathbb{N}|$.

I can easily see how to count the real numbers: $1, 2, ... $, but what I question is the diagonalization argument, since I think it can be used in the same manner to prove the natural numbers uncountable.

Comment: Please, try to write down your diagonal argument for natural numbers.

Comment: @mfl If we were to enumerate all natural numbers, S = s1 s2 ..., we can make a number x that is not part of that enumeration by choosing the 1st digit of x to be different from the 1st digit of s1. The 2nd digit of x should be different from the 2nd digit of s2. In that way, x is different from any number in S, thus x is not in S. But constructed in this way, x is indeed a natural number, and hence x is in N. Therefore, S != N.

Comment: $s_1$ is a natural number, not a digit.

Comment: Did I say it was a digit?

Comment: so how many digits do your natural numbers have? can you list all the natural numbers with only one digit? are there natural numbers with infinitely many digits?

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen In your construction, $x$ will have infinitely many nonzero digits, so it won't be a valid natural number.

Comment: @pinkwerther is that a question to my original post or my response to mfl in the comments?

Comment: that's a question to your response. a series of questions to be more precise ;)

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, but I will say that x is going towards infinity just the same way as the natural numbers in the enumeration is going towards infinity when moving down the list. I think that is what I cannot grasp.

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen One more question: Take $(S=0,1)$, a list of all one-digit natural numbers in binary notation. How would you create a number that's not in the list?

Comment: When you construct x you're giving it an infinitely long decimal expansion, which will approach a real number. But you can't do this for integers.

Comment: @pinkwerther For each element in S, I would have to add one more digit to x. So the first element 0 makes x = 1, and for the next element 1, we have not 2nd digit, thus we can just add a 1 in case of a missing digit, which makes x = 11.

Comment: @AlexZorn you are right about that, but as we move down the enumaration of natural numbers, I would say that the elements in the enumeration will approach an infinite decimal expansion in just the same way. Or am I missing something?

Comment: A number with an infinite decimal expansion can only equal an integer if every digit past the decimal point is a '0' or a '9'.

Answer (score 3):

The typical diagonal argument looks at numbers in the range $(0,1)$ expressed in decimal and by changing digits you create a new real number in that interval on the top-left to bottom-right diagonal. Each number $x_i$ in your list has a countably infinite number of digits (even if in some cases almost all of them are zero) so you can choose the $i$th digit of your new number to be different from the $i$th digit of $x_i$.

For natural numbers, you would have the diagonal running top-right to bottom-left.  Each integer $n_i$ in your list would have an infinite number of leading zeros, so your newly constructed diagonal number would have an infinite number of non-zero digits and so would not be an integer.

Comment: Once again, this is a job for our favorite hero, Archimedes Plutonium!!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is completely OK to do define all infinitely many digits of $r$ in this way, you don't have to define the digits "one a time," which means you would never finish, but can instead define them all at once.

Suppose someone claims they have a list $S$ which enumerates the interval $[0,1]$:
$$
0.x_1^1x^1_2x^1_3,\dots\\
0.x^2_1x^2_2x^3_2,\dots\\
\vdots
$$
Let $y_n = x^n_n+1$ (mod $10$), and let $$r=0.y_1y_2\dots y_n\dots$$

Notice we have defined $r$ in a single sentence, with a well-defined formula, so this defines the infinitely many digits of $r$ all at once.

Comment: There's still a technical problem, because you might end with $y_n$ to be eventually the constant $9$.

Comment: True, though the technicalities are not in the spirit of OP's confusion, so I won't try to figure them out

Comment: I was just pointing it out, having already upvoted.